# VM restarts after calling kill() more than once in a child process.

Tags: c++, linux, signals

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

void sigHandler(int sigNum){

    cout << "\nSignal has been sent." << endl;

}

int main(){

    pid_t PID = fork();

    if(PID == -1){

        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }    

    if(PID == 0){

        cout << "\nChild will now send a signal to the parent process." << endl;

        kill(getppid(), SIGINT);    

        cout << "\nChild will now send a 2nd signal." << endl;

        kill(getppid(), SIGINT);

        cout << "\nChild will now send a 3rd signal." << endl;

        kill(getppid(), SIGINT);

    }else{

        struct sigaction action;

        action.sa_handler = sigHandler;

        sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);    

        int checkErr = sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);

        if(checkErr == -1){

            perror("sigaction");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        }

        wait(NULL);

        cout << "\nParent process is now finishing." << endl;

    }
}
```

For this particular program, I am trying to send a signal from a child process to parent process three times; however, when I call kill() more than once, my VM restarts.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Which VM? It's probably a bug in your VM if that's the case. Maybe it crashes the kernel.

Comment: I am using VirtualBox.

Comment: It's also odd that the child is killing the parent. Normally the parent is responsible for killing itself if such a thing is necessary.

Comment: I intended the program to have the child sending a signal three times to the parent.

Comment: If you kill the parent, `getppid()` will return something else on the next call.  The parent's parent (grandparent)?  Or nothing?  Then the 2nd kill triggers a restart, possibly because it kills off something important in the kernel.

Comment: It might return 0, which is a bad thing to kill if you have root access.

Comment: According to https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html , sending SIGINT to systemd (pid 1) will reboot the system.